# Enabling ssl connection in Spring-boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, ssl, https

I'm using a spring boot application like a bridge between an Angular application and a Java server. The spring booT app is at the same time a server for the angular app and a client for the java server.

I need to create a Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connection.

My problem is that I don't know how to create an SSL connection between spring-boot app (like a client) and the Java server.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things before. You need to:

1. Create and make the Server side use ssl certificate (like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate))
2. Install the public key of the ssl certificate (you can download the public key part using a browser and clicking the lock icon; to do this, just have a dummy api and call it) in a keystore (JKS).
3. Make spring boot application use the JKS (-D parameter in java -jar call).